# cannot access IBM Netezza server from C# VS2013 but worked well in IBM Aginity workbench

Tags: c#, odbc, netezza

I am trying to access a Netezza server from C# .net 4.5 VS2013 on win 7.

```
   using System.Data.Odbc;
   string connstring = "Driver={NetezzaSQL};Server=MyServerIP;Database=MyDBName;Uid=MyID;Pwd=myPWD;ReadOnly=true;";
   using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connstring))
   {
            conn.ConnectionTimeout = 120;
            conn.Open(); // error 08001 
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
   }

   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

   Additional information: ERROR [08001] Client unable to establish connection
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, I see that error 08001 is

```
   The driver was unable to establish a connection with the data source.
```

From control panel --> adm tools --> Data Sources (ODBC), I checked that I have installed 
       NetezzaSQL 7.01.00.3553

It should be 64 bits, because there are no NetezzaSQL driver in Data Sources (ODBC - 32bits).

My C# code is built for Any CPU. Although I changed the build to 64 bits, I got the same error. It seems that C# code cannot find the driver ?

I can access the same server and DB from IBM Netezza Aginity workbench with the same ID and password without any problems.

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

I can access the same server and database with same Uid and Pwd from the server explorer in VS2013. But, why I cannot access it from C# code ? 
In server explorer, I right-clicked the connected server and in "Modify Connection" window, I copied the "use connection string" into my C# code.
But, it does not work!

**NEW UPDATE**
Also, I have used the same string by calling the package of "pypyodbc" in Python 3.4.1 (32 and 64 bits) on the same machine, it worked well.

It means that the nsqlodbc.dll lib of 32 and 64 bits have no problem.

I guess the problem is at C# or VS2013.

Also, in VS2013 server explorer, it can only accept 32 bits nsqlodbc.dll and establish the connection. For example, if I only installed 64 bits nsqlodbc.dll, the server explorer cannot connect the Netezza server either.

Comment: Though copying the connection string definitely should work, perhaps try the `OdbcConnectionStringBuilder` class and add keys that way?

Comment: Also, most of the connection string examples I've seen use `servername`, not `server`. I know you copied the string, but it's worth double-checking that this is the property name used.

Comment: @JeremyFortune, I have tried OdbcConnectionStringBuilder , I got the same error. Also, please see the new update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string:

```
Driver=NetezzaSQL; Server=MyServerIP; Port=5480; Database=MyDBName; Persist Security Info=true; UID=MyID; PWD=myPWD
```

Comment: No it does not work. I have installed 32 and 64 bits ODBC driver and checked the reg kys and folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64 for "odbc32.dll" and control panel --> adm tools --> ODBC driver for 64 bits. They look OK. I also tested the connection string in the OP from "ODBC Data Spurce Adm" dialog window UserDNS and System DNS tabs, the connection attempts are successful ! why I cannot access it from C# ?